# What does "simply put" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *simply put* mean in the following paragraph?

> Acoustic musical instruments are common throughout the world. **Simply put**, an acoustic instrument is any instrument that makes sound. This lecture will introduce you to an acoustic instrument invented in the 20th century.

Comment: If that's the definition being used, what other sort of musical instrument is there?

Comment: @StoneyB: It's a somewhat badly phrased definition. An acoustic instrument is one that does not need electricity to make audible music. Hence, an electric guitar, synthesizer and electric piano are examples of musical instrument that are not acoustic.

Comment: @Matt That's certainly how ***I*** use it.

Comment: @StoneyB Air guitar?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply put, *simply put* is a two-word phrase that means, *"described in basic terms,"* or *"stated in simple language,"* or, *"as an easy definition..."*

The *put* in *simply put* refers to *put into words.*

Answer (score 3):

"Simply put" is another way of saying "simply SAID."

Answer (score 3):

"Simply put" can be used to introduce an explanation or statement that might not be 100% technically correct or describe every detail, but conveys the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in the place of " put", express or  say can be used. In other words, "simply put" is "simply to say."

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answers. Adding more explanation or examples of usage would make it a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

Simply put means simply put/expressed in words

See [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-simply-simply-put)

Comment: What's the point of this answer? The accepted one already says this.